# Visual Studio 2017 not hitting breakpoints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

We have a significant code base that has been built solely on VS2013 and are now considering moving over to 2017.

However after building our functioning code base (which works fine) in 2017, symbols are no longer being loaded for debugging purposes. This means that breakpoints aren't being hit in the code when we debug it.

Has someone else happened across this issue?

Comment: Are you doing a DEBUG or a RELEASE build?  Do your DLLs have matching PDBs?

Comment: In Options => Debugging => Symbols, is VS configured to load symbols?

Comment: Yes, and yes. 
It's likely not a simple mistake on our part - but something in the environment and how it might have changed from VS13 to 17. Like if config or build files changed between them.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and I did the following:
Debug=>Options=>General => Remove the check mark for "Enable Just My Code"
This worked for me.