# See exceptions in Visual Studio when debugging on local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm debugging a web service on the local IIS but though if I set a breakpoint it *does* get hit, if an exception happens, nothing is shown on Visual Studio.

How do I get it to break and show me the error details as with desktop applications?

Comment: I think you should clean solution and delete the output (debug or release) directory,may be you are linking to dll of your library not the project of this libraries.here is one example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952401/4057416

Comment: @mohsen Didn't work. Also disabling "just my code" didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Enable breaking on all exceptions, from Debug->Windows->Exception Settings.

[image]

If your breakpoints get hit, then you're attached to the right process.
If it's an old or wrong dll, so no symbols loaded, you won't be able to see the source code, but it will still break on exceptions.

Comment: I have it like that. Didn't help.